# Import/Read CSV in Meteor.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

How can CSV files be read into a Meteor app from a filesystem path in the `/private` directory?

Found [`fast-csv`](https://github.com/C2FO/fast-csv) [packaged for Meteor](https://atmospherejs.com/chhib/fast-csv) but how can `createReadStream` be created for feeding into the `fast-csv` package.

Comment: Where are you reading the csv from (inside a package, from a filesystem path, in your private dir, etc.)?

Comment: @DavidWeldon It's from a filesystem path in the private directory

Comment: Do you actually need a CSV lib? If the encoding is simple, you may not. If you do, I'd recommend picking one that you can pass a raw string. That way you can use the assets api to read the file (easiest since it's in your private dir).

Comment: You might want to take a look at [`papa-parse`](https://atmospherejs.com/harrison/papa-parse). That's what I used in my last project and it worked well. To read file from the filesystem, look at [Node.js FS docs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html).

Comment: I've had problems with fast-csv.  Instead I recommend this library as it is more mature, better documented, and didn't have errors on the file fast-csv chocked on:  https://github.com/wdavidw/node-csv

Answer (score 2):

Using Oskar's suggestion of [papa-parse](https://atmospherejs.com/harrison/papa-parse), you can do something like this:

```
$ meteor add harrison:papa-parse
```

Then on your server:

```
// read your file as a csv string (assuming it's in the private dir)
var csv = Assets.getText('path/to/your.csv');
// convert the csv to an array of arrays
var rows = Papa.parse(csv).data;
// show the first row
console.log(rows[0]);
```

Recommended reading:

- The papa parse [documentation](http://papaparse.com/).
- [This post](http://dweldon.silvrback.com/get-text) on using the `Assets` API.

Additionally, if you are storing the data ahead of time in your `private` directory, I'd recommend converting it to a format which can be read without parsing it (i.e. use JSON instead of CSV).

Comment: Ok i spent 2 days on similar codes as posted above ... but this works at last I think Assets is the key

Comment: Hi Davide Weldon, I am trying to upload CSV in the meteor app that contains a huge amount of data. I am planning to send a file from client side and iterate (get data of) CVS on the server side, I am little bit confused Can you please suggest me the steps?

Answer (score 1):

I'd use PapaParse to read the CSV (`meteor add harrison:papa-parse`), available [here](https://atmospherejs.com/harrison/papa-parse) . It's super easy to use.

You simply have to use

```
Papa.parse("http://example.com/file.csv", {
download: true,
complete: function(results) {
    console.log(results);
}
});
```

Or, if you prefer a step-by-step approach you can use this:

```
Papa.parse("http://example.com/big.csv", {
download: true,
step: function(row) {
    console.log("Row:", row.data);
},
complete: function() {
    console.log("All done!");
}
```

});

IMHO it's a very good package, I've used it extensively. More docs [here]. Enjoy![2](http://papaparse.com/)